# How to estimate memory needed for a cosine_similarity matrix?

Tags: memory-management, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm trying to compute a cosine_similarity matrix by `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`. The output matrix might be 60k*50k. However, it returns a MemoryError with 32G memory. I'm considering to add more memory to my server, however I'd like to estimate how much more do I really need.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using 64-bit python ? (32-bit python is a common cause of memory errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good estimate of the required memory would be 60,000 * 50,000 * 4 bytes = 12 gigabytes. If you are using doubles instead of floats it would be twice as much memory.

Comment: You can do some float hashing (quantization) but that can be lossy: http://oldweb.mit.bme.hu/books/quantization/floating-point.pdf. In Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize